# Python mock attributes defined and set within __init__

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-mock

I am trying to write some unit tests for an application and I using python mock. I am familiar with other mocking libraries and haven't had much trouble until now. I am trying to mock a chained call on an attribute set within the **init** block of the parent class. Here is an example of what I need:

```
class ApplicationUnderTest:

    def __init__(self):
      self.attributeBeginningChain = SomeClass(False)

    def methodWithChain(self):
      object = self.attributeBeginningChain.methodOfSomeClass()
```

I need the chained call to throw an error. I have tried resolving this in the following manner:

```
@patch.object(SomeClass(False), 'methodOfSomeClass', side_effect=ErrorClass)
def test_chained_call(self, mock_someclass):
    A = ApplicationUnderTest.methodWithChain()
    self.assertTrue(mock_someclass.called)
```

The last assertion fails so I am pretty sure this isn't the way to do this. I have also tried:

```
@patch('ApplicationUnderTest.attributeBeginningChain')
def test_chained_call(self, mock_someclass):
    mock_someclass.methodOfSomeClass.side_effect = ErrorClass
    A = ApplicationUnderTest.methodWithChain()
    self.assertTrue(mock_someclass.called)
```

That throws the error:

```
AttributeError: package.ApplicationUnderTest does not have the attribute 'attributeBeginningChain'
```

I cannot make alterations to the code under test, so my question is how can I mock chained calls made on attributes set under the 
_init__ function? I have read that this is not possible but surely there must be a work around? Can I perhaps somehow instruct the mock fixture to react to the call itself rather than the attribute object via autospec?

Answer (score 1):

`attributeBeginningChain` instance attribute is set by `__init__` so the patched static value that you set by `patch` call in `ApplicationUnderTest` call will  be override by `__init__` call.

You should patch `ApplicationUnderTest` instance instead:

```
def test_chained_call(self):
    A = ApplicationUnderTest()
    with patch.object(A, 'attributeBeginningChain') as mock_someclass:
        mock_someclass.methodOfSomeClass.side_effect = ErrorClass
        with self.assertRaise(ErrorClass):
            A.methodWithChain()
```

Another possibility is to patch directly `SomeClass.methodOfSomeClass`

```
@patch('package.SomeClass.methodOfSomeClass', side_effect=ErrorClass)
def test_chained_call(self, mock_methodOfSomeClass):
    with self.assertRaise(ErrorClass):
        ApplicationUnderTest().methodWithChain()
```

I'm not sure where your objects are and so how you should patch them: take a look at [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) to understand how you should use `patch` calls.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I haven't tried this yet (moved on to other things) but I will check this out and respond when I get back to it.